# why typedef void (*f_ptr)(int); and typedef void (*f_ptr)(); work the same in C?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I accidentally forgot to add (int) when defining a function pointer, and my program still worked.
I wold like to know if there is any case where it would not work. 
my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(int var)
{
    printf("this is f1 and var is: %d\n", var);
}

void f2(int var)
{
    printf("this is f2 and var is: %d\n", var);
}

void f3(int var)
{
    printf("this is f3 and var is: %d\n", var);
}
typedef void (*f_ptr)(int);
// pq eu poderia escrever: typedef void (*f_ptr)(); e o programa funcionaria normalmente?
typedef int n_casa;

int main()
{
    f_ptr ptr[] = {f1, f2, f3};

    int c = 0;
    while (c < 3)
    {   
        ptr[c](c);
        ++c;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

both `typedef void (*f_ptr)(int);` and `typedef void (*f_ptr)();` worked in my program.

Comment: They don’t. That is, the two function pointers don’t work the same way. One insists on one integer argument, the other allows any number of argument any type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different.

`typedef void (*f_ptr)(int)` declares a funciton pointer that takes only one `int` argument, and returns nothing.

While for `typedef void (*f_ptr)()`, the function pointer takes an UNSPECIFIED number of arguments, and returns nothing.

[According to the SEI CERT C Coding Standard](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/DCL20-C.+Explicitly+specify+void+when+a+function+accepts+no+arguments), it is recommended to *explicitly specify `void` when a function accepts no arguments.*

Comment: What is missing is why with `typedef void (*f_ptr)();` and `void f1(int var)`, is `f_ptr ptr[] = {f1, f2, f3};` is OK as the types differ - but perhaps not different enough.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: specifically, they are [*compatible types*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7).

Comment: And in particular, see http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15

Answer (score -1):

From my little assembly experience: When you call a function with an argument, it pushes the argument onto the stack and then executes the function. Then the function reads the arguments from the top of the stack.

If you call f_ptr with no arguments, you won't get an error, you'll just get a garbage value in `var`. If you call it with 100 arguments, you'll just get the first one.

I think the only reason the compiler doesn't stop you is that it isn't smart enough to.